# AutoMapper 9 generic extension static class

Tags: .net-core, automapper

I would like some help.

I have a generic class using Automapper 8 maas when I put AutoMappar 9 stopped working.
I looked for a solution but did not find someone can help me?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Intranet.Services.Extensions {

    internal static class AutoMapperExtensions {

        public static T MapTo<T>(this object value)
        {
            return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<T>(value);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> EnumerableTo<T>(this object value)
        {
            return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<T>>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

> T AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(object source) An object reference is
>   required for the non-static field, method, or property
>   'Mapper.Map(object)' (CS0120)

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/9.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Comment: Hi Lucian,
Thank you. I had already looked at the documentation and understood that it does not do more.
I figured someone would have an alternative.
Instead of mapping straight into the controls, I wanted to keep an extension.
I will change the coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoMapper 9 wants you to use dependancy injection. This added a whole level of complexity to my legacy project that I just didn't want to deal with.

So I just reverse engineered what it was doing before and wrote a wrapper for it.

```
public static class MapperWrapper 
{
    private const string InvalidOperationMessage = "Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.";
    private const string AlreadyInitialized = "Mapper already initialized. You must call Initialize once per application domain/process.";

    private static IConfigurationProvider _configuration;
    private static IMapper _instance;

    private static IConfigurationProvider Configuration
    {
        get => _configuration ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(InvalidOperationMessage);
        set => _configuration = (_configuration == null) ? value : throw new InvalidOperationException(AlreadyInitialized);
    }

    public static IMapper Mapper
    {
        get => _instance ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(InvalidOperationMessage);
        private set => _instance = value;
    }

    public static void Initialize(Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression> config)
    {
        Initialize(new MapperConfiguration(config));
    }

    public static void Initialize(MapperConfiguration config)
    {
        Configuration = config;
        Mapper = Configuration.CreateMapper();
    }

    public static void AssertConfigurationIsValid() => Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

To use it just Add MapperWrapper before your old Mapper call.

```
 MapperWrapper.Mapper.Map<Foo2>(Foo1);
```